# Typescript Generic Constraint where the property of one type depends on the other

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm attempting to create a function that in use will look like this:

```
Foo(Number, (aNum: number) => {});
```

I am attempting to make this generic where the parameter of the callback in the second argument must be of the same type as the first.

The type in the first was easy:

```
function getObjectConstructor() {
  return Object.prototype.constructor;
}

type Type = ReturnType<typeof getObjectConstructor>

function thing(a: Type): void {
  console.log(a.name);
}

thing(Number);
```

However I am a little stuck on creating this dependency, basically I'm trying to read the name property value from Type and get the name from the second type and see if they match. Something like this:

```
interface HasName {
  name: string;
}

interface HasConstructor {
  constructor: HasName
}

function AreSameName<T extends Type, U extends HasConstructor>(a: T, b: U) {
  return a.name === b.constructor.name
}
```

But as a generic constraint.  I'm not sure if this is possible, I'm new to Typescript.

Comment: I'm confused... is the first argument to `Foo()` supposed to be a *function* (which is *callable*) or a *constructor* (which is *newable*)?  Also, your `Type` type is equivalent to just `Function`, since `Object.prototype.constructor` is only known to be a `Function`... so I'm not sure why you've included `getObjectConstructor()` in your example; if it's not necessary for your question you might want to remove it (since example code should ideally be a [mcve] and unnecessary code is not minimal).

Comment: and  assuming `a` is a constructor, is there some reason why you want to use `a.name === b.constructor.name` instead of `b instanceof a`?  Names are just strings and you can easily have two different types with the same constructor name: [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQQE4FMDKBDAtugOT3QB4AVRdADynTABMBnRAbwF8A+ACgChF-E0OKgBciMOgDuiLgDp52VAHNGY7GACeASkQBeDojIAaPgJhhGUdRHRiyPHS1P8MUEKiRDUssMT27dRHNLa3RZCARLVBAvH2IeNh4eCIsoFD1BABtsRmZkVkRElMtEACEMiGzc9JZC5Mi0gCMMiWlSri0AbnqLOEywzLglLjQsYiJ8EaNERq0uxAB6BcQoaPQexj6Boa5m4KtIdDhgFHmlxGBsTMZ1niA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `name` property of a function is typed as a `string`, so you don't have a string literal at compile time. You won't be able to cause compile errors based on the value of `name`.

As a possible alternative, you may be able to constraint the type of the second parameter to the `InstanceType` of the first parameter. (`InstanceType<T>` is the type you get when using the `new` operator on `T`.) See [this example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/FAEwpgxgNghgTmABAMwK4DsIBcCWB7dRLMAZywB4AVRMAD2PRBMXTAHdEAKAOl-gHMSALkQx0ATwDaAXQCUiALwA+URKWdgiRNjxwRlADSIAbjCiowIgJLoyYiGEriADmCpLgskcbw4QAbmBgYjJOADlUAFsAIzA4IwBGACYAZllAkKxwqNj4xAAiZJT89ODSLIBlLDgcdH5E1NLMziqauqNC1JLA4AB6XsQAeWiAK0gsFAxsfEIELFQ4WwKxcXyjEjxVcSwAC1r+RH48Ul5uMtDhsewGtJ7oGBJmAEFEAG9NRGca02JEWhEyG0DgoCjswFAoHh8oEAL5Be6PRAAITeHy+OB+SHEInQOTiikQRVhQWaTw6RW65yySKMrA4T04sia5U4NJY7GRjNKQA):

```
declare function test<T extends new (...args: any[]) => any>(
    ctor: T, value: InstanceType<T>
): any;

test(Number, 123);
test(Number, "123"); // Error: string is not assignable to number.
test(String, 123); // Error: number is not assignable to string.
test(String, "123");

// Object function returns "any", so anything goes...
test(Object, 123);

class A {
  private x: string = "hello";
}

class B {
  private y: number = 123;
}

test(A, "123"); // Error: string is not assignable to A.
test(B, new A()); // Error: A is not assignable to B.
test(B, new B());
```

Comment: That is what I was looking to try and do, thank you

Comment: Thank again, I have provided a github repo with the function I was attempting to write https://github.com/neal83/TypeSwitch